# Summing of digits for large numbers

Tags: number-theory

Are there any ways to sum the digits of numbers that are especially big. I have searched for any solutions on stackexchange but could not really find methods that are more informative.

For example, summing the digits of $2000^{2000}$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think it's possible to sum those digits? Do you have some application in mind for the sum?

Comment: It's $2704$, obviously.

Comment: I dont really have any applications in mind on how to go about doing it. If you dont mind, can you drop me some hints? Thank you

Comment: Hello Lucian, thank you for your input. May i know the method that you employed to solve the question? Thank you

Comment: For what it's worth, the sum of the (decimal) digits of $2^n$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A001370 where there are a couple of references that could prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general method to find the number of digits of a vary large number, but there will be some simplifications, for example the sum of digits of $2000^{2000}$ is the same as the sum of digits of $2^{2000}$ but here we cannot determine the sum of digits of this number without using a calculator.

Comment: Okay. But how do we get about knowing that the sum of digits of 2000^2000 is the same as 2^2000? How about numbers like 2014^2014? Will it simplified to the sum of digits of some other numbers? Thank you!

Comment: bacause $2000^{2000}=2^{2000}\cdot 1000^{2000}=2^{2000}\cdot 10^{6000}$ but the multiplication by powers of $10$ does not change anything to the sum (adding $0$'s in the right) so we can elimenate them

Comment: for $2014^{2014}$ I'm afraid you can deduce anything